# How to install ngx_http_ssi_module

Tags: nginx

default NGINX configuration not included SSI module (don't confuse with SSL)
in my case

```
# nginx -V 
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 
-fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-lUTckl/nginx-1.18.0=. 
-fstack-protector-strong 
-Wformat 
-Werror=format-security 
-fPIC 
-Wdate-time 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid 
--modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--with-debug 
--with-compat  
--with-pcre-jit 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_auth_request_module 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_slice_module 
--with-threads 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic 
--with-stream=dynamic 
--with-stream_ssl_module 
--with-mail=dynamic 
--with-mail_ssl_module
```

ngx_http_ssi_module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) is missing. How to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu versions which ship NGINX 1.18.0 (including Jammy 22.04), you need to install the `nginx-full` flavor of the package.  Just doing `sudo apt install nginx` will install `nginx-core` which contains a very very limited set of third party modules and leaves most of the optional modules disabled.

You can do this by doing `sudo apt install nginx nginx-full` which will replace `nginx-core` with `nginx-full` and install all that `nginx-full` contains in place of `nginx-core`.  Your configuration should *not* be affected, however make sure you take a backup of `/etc/nginx` before executing the change and switch.

Then the SSI module will be present.

Be advised that the NGINX docs state that "**Currently, the list of supported SSI commands is incomplete.**", therefore not all SSI commands will work or necessarily be documented or available. (emphasis is mine, but this is a direct quote from the docs you linked)